# Some insight about this integral limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Given $u:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and has compact support, we define the set $$K_u: = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^N : u(x) = \|u\|_\infty\}.$$

Looking at the following limit 
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u|^p d\mu}{\|u\|_p^p} = 1.$$

When $K$ defined as above, and if the Lebesgue measure $\mu(K) >0$, we break up the above integral into $K$ and $K^c$
$$1 = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \int_{K} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu+ \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\int_{K^c} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu.$$
The first integral over $K$ 
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \int_{K} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = \frac{1}{\mu(K)} \int_{K} 1 d\mu = 1.$$
This is because on $K$, the integrand is the following
\begin{align*}
&\left(\frac{\| u\|_\infty}{\|u\|_p}\right)^{p}\\
=& \frac{\|u\|_\infty^p}{\int_{K} |u|^p dx + \int_{K^c} |u|^p dx }\\
=& \frac{\|u\|_\infty^p}{\| u\|_\infty^p m(K) + \|u\|_\infty^p \int_{K^c} \left(\frac{| u|}{\| u\|_\infty}\right)^p dx}\\
=& \frac{1}{\mu(K) + \int_{K^c} \left(\frac{| u|}{\| u\|_\infty}\right)^p dx} 
\end{align*}
which converges to  $\frac{1}{\mu(K)}$ as $p$ goes to infinity.

Therefore the limit of the second integral over $K^c$ has to be zero
$$ \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\int_{K^c} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu = 0. \quad\quad \text{ if } \mu(K)>0 \quad (\star)$$

However when $\mu(K) = 0$, integral over $K^c$ is the same as integral over $\mathbb{R}^N$ we have

$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty}\int_{K^c} \bigg(\frac{|u|} {\|u\|_p}\bigg)^p d\mu   = 1 \quad\quad \text{ if } \mu(K)=0  \quad (\star\star)$$
which is different from $(\star)$ above.

Can you give me some insight about cause of the two limits being different.
Thank you!

Comment: Two comments: 1. $K$ is a set of points, so what does it mean by $u(x)=a$ a.e. for a given point $x$? 2. I think you use $\int_{K^c} \left(\frac{| u|}{\| u\|_\infty}\right)^p dx\to 0$ as $p\to \infty$ for $\mu(K)>0$, but why it's true given $\mu(K^c)=\infty$ (assume Lebesgue measure)?

Comment: To show $\lim_p \int_K \cdots=1$, you use integrand converges to $\frac{1}{\mu(K)}$, which need $\int_{K^c} \left(\frac{| u|}{\| u\|_\infty}\right)^p dx\to 0$. Why it's true?

Comment: @JohnZHANG.  I agree with your 1.  I think in 2., it's because the integrand converges pointwise to zero (remember $K^c=\{|u|<||u||_\infty\}$ if we ignore the pesky a.e.) and is dominated by the characteristic function of the support of $u$.

Comment: @JohnZHANG I showed that $lim_p \int_K \cdots = \frac{1}{\mu(K)} \int_K d\mu = 1$ and this is independent of the second integral over $K^c$. And $\int_{K^c} \bigg( \frac{|u|}{\|u\|_\infty}\bigg)^p dx \rightarrow 0$ this is from Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. Observe that the denominator is $\|u\|_\infty$, not $\|u\|_p$.

Comment: @ForgotALot I see. Thanks, I forget integrand is $0$ outside $K$.

Comment: The integrand is $0$ outside the support of $u$ which is assumed to be compact.  Actually, I'm assuming that $\mu$ assigns finite measure to compact sets, like Lebesgue measure does.

Comment: @ForgotALot Yes, it is Lebesgue measure. And I changed $u$ to continuous so that I can make the set $K$ precise.

Answer (score 1):

The best intuition I can get for your result comes from one dimension.  Think of $u$ as being $1$ on an interval $(a,b)$ and then diminishing down to $0$ outside a bigger interval $(c,d)\supset (a,b)$.  As you exponentiate $u$ to higher and higher powers, it becomes dominated by what happens on $(a,b)$ and goes to zero outside $(a,b)$.  Also, no matter how large you make $p$, $||u||_p$ is bounded below by $(b-a)^{1/p}\to 1$.  In contrast, if $a=b$, so the function reaches a peak at $a=b$ and falls to $0$ on both sides, the set of measure zero $[a,b]$ won't influence anything, and what is more $||u||_p^p\to0$ as $p\to\infty$, quite different behavior.

By the way, in your second displayed equation, not only is the limit $1$, but the integrals are $1$ for every $p$.